# Does electrical energy depend upon number of charges particles

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, charge, potential-energy, voltage

This might sound silly,but,electrons in electric current carry electrical energy,so,does electrical energy depend upon the number of electrons?like if in a area,more electrons are flowing,then there will be more electrical energy,compared to less surface area,if the voltage source is constant?

Comment: Things besides electrons carry current as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric energy through  current flowing
you have E=U*I*t, so with fixed voltage, energy will be higher with higher current, and this are more electrons going through any area of your circuit per second.